# Passing multiple objects to function parameter at once

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, callback

I'm writing a program (in JavaScript) that will determine the most suitable car based on a user's needs. I have 4 objects, each one a different car. For simplification purposes I will provide one object as an example. Assume there are 3 other objects with the same properties in my code (Fiat, Audi, BMW, etc.).

```
var chevy = {
  make: "Chevy",
  model: "Bel Air",
  year: 1957,
  color: "red",
  passengers: 2,
  convertible: false,
  mileage: 1021
};
```

The goal is to pass each object as an argument to a function, and return a boolean value based on conditionals. Here is the function:

```
function prequal(car) {
  if (car.mileage > 10000) {
    return false;
  }
  else if (car.year > 1960) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And calling the function:

```
var worthALook = prequal(taxi);
  if (worthALook) {
    console.log("You gotta check out this " + taxi.make + " " + taxi.model);
  }
  else {
    console.log("You should really pass on the " + taxi.make + " " +    taxi.model);
}
```

Do I have to call each object seperately? Or is there a simplified way of calling the function for all 4 objects at once? I'm new to this and working through this problem spiked my curiosity.

Thanks!!

EDIT: Sorry for the rambling but I seem to have figured out a solution. I am getting the desired output by using a nested function:

```
function worthALook(car) {    
    var shouldYouBuy = prequal(car);
        if (shouldYouBuy) {
            console.log("You gotta check out this " + car.model);    
        }
        else {
            console.log("You should really pass on this " + car.model);
        }
}
```

calling the original 'prequal' function (see above) inside the 'worthALook' function outputs:

```
You should really pass on this Taxi
You should really pass on this Cadillac
You gotta check out this Bel Air
You should really pass on this 500
```

After each object I called the worthALook function like so:

```
worthALook(chevy);
worthALook(fiat);
```

etc.

I received my desired output but does my code seem like overkill?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the objects in an `Array` and filter what's worth a look. Return that object instead of a boolean.

```
function worthALook(){
   return ([].filter.call(arguments, prequal) || [false])[0];
   /* remove [0] from the above line and change [false] to false if you
   want to return multiple cars that satisfy a condition. Use indexes if you do that */
}

var car = worthALook(chevy, fiat, audi, bmw); // pass inas many as you want
if(car) // check if it's a car
   console.log("You gotta check out this " + taxi.make + " " + taxi.model);
```

The return statement is used with `||` so even if none of the cars satisfy the condition, then you could return `false`. Also, we are using `arguments` object, so you can pass in as many `car` objects to the `worthALook` function, which will make use of `prequal` function to filter 'em.

Comment: I will test this function out in my code, thanks for the quick response! Check my edit in the OP if you're curious to see my workaround.

Comment: @jake.wies yeah. Saw it. But you're right about it being overkill. Also check my edit too.